# Weird Sys.time() when used in cbind()

Tags: r, cbind

Can anyone explain to me why a normal `Sys.time()`

```
> Sys.time()
[1] "2013-05-06 23:23:22 CEST"
```

changes into

```
> cbind(Sys.time(), 1:5)
            [,1] [,2]
  [1,] 1367875299    1
  [2,] 1367875299    2
  [3,] 1367875299    3
  [4,] 1367875299    4
  [5,] 1367875299    5
```

when using cbind?

Answer (score 2):

It gets converted to `numeric`, when you `cbind` (because the result is a `matrix` and can keep only one type of an object):

```
as.numeric(Sys.time())
# [1] 1367875892
```

Contrast with:

```
cbind(Sys.time(), data.frame(1:5))
           Sys.time() X1.5
#1 2013-05-06 16:33:27    1
#2 2013-05-06 16:33:27    2
#3 2013-05-06 16:33:27    3
#4 2013-05-06 16:33:27    4
#5 2013-05-06 16:33:27    5
```

Multiple types are ok here.

Comment: So then I can use: `data.frame(Sys.time(), 1:5)`. Thanks. What is the conversion used here though? What do the numbers mean?

Comment: It's seconds since epoch (01/01/1970 iirc)

Comment: `data.frame(Sys.time(), 1:5)` would be even better: cbinding columns together is a bad habit to get into